# how to create a string variable using int variables in c

Tags: c

I'm very new to C. I want to construct a string using 3 integers and "/".

Eg.

```
int a=01;
int b=10;
int c=2012;

char date = "a/b/c";
```

Can you please help and let me know what is the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot store string in `char`, which can contain only one character (typically one byte).

Comment: Simply : String is an `array` of `characters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    int b=10;
    int c=2012;
    char date[11];

    sprintf(date, "%d/%d/%d", a, b, c);
    printf("%s\n", date);

    sprintf(date, "%02d/%02d/%04d", a, b, c);
    printf("%s\n", date);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints the date in two formats.  The second zero-pads while the first does not.  Here's the output:

```
1/10/2012
01/10/2012
```

Comment: You should add `#include <stdio.h>` to the top of your code to use `printf()` and `sprintf()`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks, I had that in my code but missed it when I copied/pasted.  I added it.

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate enough buffer and use `sprintf()`.

```
int a=01; /* this is octal value */
int b=10;
int c=2012;

char date[40]; /* 32-bit long integer will be at most 11 digits including sign in decimal */
sprintf(date, "%d/%d/%d", a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf`, which will write to a string, as the name suggests: `string print function`:

```
sprintf(date, "%d/%d/%d", a, b, c);
```

and include the header `stdio.h`.

Also, doing

```
char date;
```

makes `date` a character, but you want it to be a string. So allocate memory in it:

```
char date [10];
```

which makes it a string or an array of characters with 10 elements. But you will be able to store only 9 characters in it, as you have to keep one  element for the null-terminator or `\0`.

---

***How does `sprintf` work?***

If you're confused what `sprintf` is doing, basically the first argument is where `sprintf` is printing, the second argument is what to print, and the third, fourth, etc.. arguments are variables which will be substituted by a `%d`, `%s`, etc.

For a better explanation, see [this](https://blog.udemy.com/sprintf-c/):

> The C library function `sprintf ()` is used to store formatted data as a string. You can also say the `sprintf ()` function is used to create strings as output using formatted data. The syntax of the `sprintf ()` function is as follows:
>
> ```
> int sprintf (char *string, const char *form, … );
> ```

---

You can also use `itoa`, but it is not standard.